# AngularJs and Webpack - How to import services, components and modules

Tags: angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I've started using webpack in quite a large code base and have been using ES6's import statement to load the required dependencies for each module.

My file structure aims to be component based, with all the pieces specific to a component inside that component's folder. For example, the component file itself, and then templates, stylesheets, services, filters, etc, also specific to that component. Then we may have a generic service folder inside that module for services that are not specific to a particular component. eg:

```
- my-module
  - component-a
    - component_a.component.js
    - component_a.component.spec.js
    - component_a.html
    - component_a.scss
  - services
    - some_service.service.js
  main.module.js
  main.run.js
  main.config.js
```

My problem is that the `main.module.js` file is becoming unmaintainable, as I manually import all the required dependencies into this file and then register them into the angular world as required. eg:

```
import componentA from './component-a/component_a.component';
import someService from './services/some_service.service;

angular
  .module('myModule', [])
  .component('componentA', componentA)
  .service('someService', someService);
```

You can imagine what this starts to look like when you have 10+ components. I've struggled to find a good solution for this problem, does anyone have any suggestions? Is there a best practice approach here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, every component/controller/service etc. can connect itself to the app in their own file.

Like you have got a file `ome_service.service.js` and inside you write:

```
myApp.service('omeService', function(){
    var app = this;
    // service stuff
});
```

So the registration is not in your `main.module.js` but in every file itself.
Although, you need to expose your app variable to be globally available. With a bundler like webpack this is easily handled. Gene Conroy-Jones wrote a nice post about how to make it possible via webpack here: https://medium.com/@drgenejones/using-webpack-with-legacy-angular-spas-automating-imports-using-require-context-58e0e9cc6e9c

With this approach, every new component would handle its registration on their own, and the central app would not have to carry all those imports.